# Getting practice with pandas & numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I just finished reading some books about pandas, numpy & matplotlib and thought about getting some practice.
Unfortunately, I am a bit lost on how to start. 
Can anyone recommend a site, which provides csv-files to practice on?
I have found some sites like kaggle or data.gov, but they just have files, which are already cleaned etc.
I'm also open to other ways on how to practice those libraries.
Grateful for every answer.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Just Search the Web. Using e.g. Google seach for *Pandas tutorial*,
*Numpy tutorial* and so on.

Even the home site of *matplotlib* contains a couple of introductory
tutorials. See e.g. https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html

A good source of knowledge is also *stackoverflow* itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding some interesting datasets on: [icpsr.umich.edu](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/pages/)

In my experience, these sets often contain missing values and values that need formatting, which could be good for practice.

Some datasets are public, but many require will require special credentials. If you are a university student, this often qualifies.